# Как получить first_name из callbackquery в aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я делаю телеграм бота и хочу сделать интерактив между пользователями бота с помощью кнопок,
подскажите как сделать чтобы получать `first_name` другого человека из callback. Я могу получить свой `first_name` используя `callback.from_user.first_name` , но как мне вытащить `first_name` из сообщения на которое я ответил. Выглядит это так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['rp', 'рп'])
async def roleplay(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
    return await message.reply('Команда должна быть ответом на сообщение!')
    elif message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply('Доступные взаимодействия', reply_markup=togrp_kb1)
```

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='smile')
async def smile(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.edit_text(text=f'{callback.from_user.first_name} улыбнулся {какому-то пользователю}')
```

То есть я пишу `/rp` ответом на сообщение у меня появляется кнопка и при нажатии на кнопку, сообщение редактируется и там какое-то действие. Я пытался доставать так `callback.message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name`
Но он достаёт моё имя.
А нужен другой пользователь. Может как то получать из get_chat_member? Как поступить? Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как я не нашел способ чтобы получить другого пользователя через `callback`.
Было принято решение просто отказаться от кнопок в данном случае, а просто использовать обычные штатные команды, то есть `/hug @user`, то есть использовать в качестве обработчика событий `@dp.message.handler(commands=['hug'])`.
Таким образом можно проще получить другого пользователя используя метод `get_args`, который берет аргументы после команды.
В ответ будет получаться что текущий пользователь обнял указанного.
Пример: `/hug @Alice`
`Миша обнял пользователя @Alice`.
Так и решается данная проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Данный вопрос решил так:

Используя `global`

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['rp', 'рп'])
async def roleplay(message: types.Message):
    global otherusername
    otherusername = message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name
    if not message.reply_to_message:
    return await message.reply('Команда должна быть ответом на сообщение!')
    elif message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply('Доступные взаимодействия', reply_markup=togrp_kb1)
```

Затем нажимаем на кнопку

В самой кнопке код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='smile')
async def smile(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.edit_text(text=f'{callback.from_user.first_name} улыбнулся {otherusername}')
```

В ответ получаем сообщение по типу: `Миша` *улыбнулся* `Вася`

Comment: Вы не решили данный вопрос, а что будет, если несколько пользователей сразу напишут команду?

Comment: Я понимаю что не совсем решил данный вопрос, но к сожалению иного выхода я не смог придумать. 
В моем вопросе, данный пример является решением. Для этого я и писал сюда, чтобы мне помогли найти решение данного вопроса. Но ответ слишком долго не давался, а решения я не мог найти, поэтому пришлось делать это через некий "велосипед". Если у вас есть совет как бы можно было улучшить данный код, буду признателен за информацию.

Comment: Благодарю что обратили мое внимание на данную ошибку.